What's the best practice to storing encoded data on-chain?
I need to store some encoded data on-chain that I can then decode to obtain the original data. The idea is that this data comes in the form of a JSON.
Is it possible to do this? Must fields in the JSON blob be fixed in size so I can always get the same size for the encoded result?

The best way I found to achieve this is by encoding the JSON object to base64, using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38134374/13327102
That way, I can just store the string representation of the JSON object on-chain and decode it off-chain when needed, to get the original JSON object.
For reference, there is also a function that lets you encode a JSON to base64 using Solidity: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#Base64

As already mentioned, there is no such thing as "unhashing". I guess you are referring to encryption and decryption?
You can encrypt your data off-chain with whatever algorithm you want. Then you can store the encrypted data on-chain, in some bytes32[] or strings or something.
The problem with storing any data like this is the cost. Ethereum is very expensive for data storage and shouldn't be considered for stuff like JSON storage.
Storage is cheaper in other EVM compatible chains, but still those are not meant to be used as data storage.

Hashes are one way. "Unhashing" is not possible. That's the point of the hash .
EDIT
Solidity doesn't have any encryption or decryption methods as of yet .
You need to carry it out offchain .

Ok. Can I encrypt/decrypt instead then?

@FalconStakepool Edit made

@FalconStakepool Whats your application ?
